# Where can I get a closed loop iPhone carrying case/holster?

Tags: iphone

Most of my older gear with belt carrying cases have a closed loop. In all but one (shoddy) iPhone case I've seen, there is no closed loop, only a clip that can slide off.

Are there any iPhone holsters/carrying cases which have an old-fashioned closed loop or other hardware that would prevent the case from accidentally sliding up and off my belt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ripoffs [CO-IQ holster](http://ripoffholstersonline.com/ripoffs-co--iq.html) can be ordered with a belt loop (which is technically a BL-IQ using the RipOffs model number system). This is a low-profile, plain black nylon holster with a flap covering/securing the phone. At one time Ripoffs also made a CO-IP model for the iPhone, but it is no longer listed in their catalog.

[image: Ripoffs Holster]

If you're looking for something more *tactical*, Maxpedition's [5" Clip-On Phone Holster](http://www.maxpedition.com/store/pc/5-CLIP-ON-PHONE-HOLSTER-8p444.htm#details) can be adapted by using their TacTie Attachment straps as a belt loop. (You could also sew a nylon strap onto existing MOLLE loops to form a full-time belt loop.)

[image: MaxPedition Front][image: MaxPedition Side][image: MaxPedition with TacTies]

The 5.11 [C5 Case-L](http://www.511tactical.com/All-Products/Bags-Backpacks/Pouches/C5-Case-L-PhonePDA.html?) can be snapped securely to a belt or attached to a MOLLE system. (The new style 5.11 tactical pants have a flap pocket especially designed for an iPhone that makes a belt case superfluous.)

[image: 5.11 C5]

Although I don't own any of these particular products, I've owned pouches, holsters and bags (and pants) from these manufacturers and am comfortable vouching for the overall quality of their products.

Check your local Police/EMS supply shops if you want a local source. You may find other options there too—secure carry of smartphones is definitely something of interest to LEOS, EMTs, etc.

Comment: Finally, after a couple of attempts at ordering, I received my Ripoffs CO-IQ holster and I am nothing short of delighted. I remain, however, mystified why cell phone holster manufacturers believe that only tactical customers want belt holsters that are not coming off accidentally short of force majeure.

Comment: I suspect that case manufacturers, and *many* customers are overly sensitized to the *utility belt* remarks that full-flap holsters cultivate. I was once a card-carrying member of the holster brigade myself, but have worked to trim my EDC (every day carry) to the point where I can *usually* just use my pockets—and try to select pants accordingly. YMMV. FWIW, I just found my first Rip-Offs holster - purchased to accommodate a Nokia phone over 15 years ago - sitting in a box. Pulled the clip, ran it through a wash cycle it looks good as new—if only I had something to put in it.